# How to install PHP 5.3.18 on Amazon EC2?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I am googling for a while but with no luck. I am looking for quickest way of installing PHP in  5.3.x version on Amazon EC2.

Could someone give me any advice?

Comment: which OS do you have?

Comment: What did you try? what destro are you using?

Answer (score 1):

**For PHP 5.3.x:**

```
sudo yum install -y php
sudo yum install -y php-devel
```

**For PHP 5.4:**

```
sudo yum install -y php54
```

---

Information taken from:

- [Install PHP 5.4, Apache 2.4, and PHP-APC on Amazon Linux EC2](http://www.codingsteps.com/install-apache-2-4-php-5-4-php-apc-on-amazon-ec2-with-amazon-linux/)
- [Install PHP, Apache, PHP-APC, and MySQL on Amazon Linux EC2](http://www.codingsteps.com/install-apache-php-apc-mysql-on-amazon-ec2-with-amazon-linux-ami/)